# How to make Link/NavLink path shorter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router to create links. The homepage has a signup/login button that directs you to my Signup-Login component (url.com/signup-login). The signup/login page has separate links for signup and login. I want those links to have paths url.com/signup and url.com/login, not url.com/signup-login/signup and url.com/signup-login/login. Is there any way for me to do this?

**EDIT 1:**

App (main page):

```
<Header/>
<Route path="/signup-login" component={Signup-Login}/>
<Footer/>
```

Header (basic Signup/Login link):

```
<NavLink to="/signup-login">Sign Up/Log In</NavLink>
```

Signup-Login Page (two links):

```
<NavLink to="./signup-login/signup">Signup!</NavLink>
<NavLink to="./signup-login/login">Login!</NavLink>

<Switch>
   <Route path="/signup-login/signup" component={Signup} />
   <Route path="/signup-login/login" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

I've tried NavLink to="/signup" and Route path="/signup" but it fails. I need the "signup-login/signup" for it to work. Is there any way for me to rewrite the url path? Do I have to make it nested?

Here's is an example of what the Signup-Login page may look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you include your `Router`, the buttons `onClick` in the signup and login components, also the `NavLink` elements as they are in the project?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the routes for /login and /signup on your main page you should have access to use a NavLink with that path anywhere underneath it

Main App

```
<Header/>
<Switch>
    <Route path="/signup-login" component={Signup-Login}/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
</Switch>
<Footer/>
```

Signup-Login Page (does not need the Switch/Routes anymore)

```
<NavLink to="/signup">Signup!</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/login">Login!</NavLink>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when I put the route path on my Main App, it shows the Login or Signup page separately on the main page, as opposed to the Signup or Login components showing up underneath the navlinks on my Signup_Login page